# Slow drawing on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, arduino

I am trying to get data from an Arduino one, and draw it using the matplotlib librarie. I accomplish to do this (get the data) and also to draw it.

The problem comes while drawing. It is too slow, knowing that the Nyquist frequency that I am using to send the data is about 20 [kHz].

This is my code:

```
class ViewWidget(QMainWindow):

  live_data = []
  cnt = 0

  def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)

    self.figure_canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())
    layout.addWidget(self.figure_canvas, 10)

    self.axes = self.figure_canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)

    self.x = ViewWidget.live_data

  def seeData(self):
    arduinoData = serial.Serial("com4", 9600)

    while True:
        if arduinoData.inWaiting()>0:
            arduinoString = arduinoData.read(arduinoData.inWaiting())
            ardString = map(ord, arduinoString)
            for number in ardString:
                numb = float(number/77.57)
                ViewWidget.live_data.append(numb)                       
                drawnow(self.makeFig)
        else:
            print "There is no data"

  def makeFig(self):
    self.axes.plot(self.x, picker = 5)
    self.figure_canvas.draw()
```

Am i missing something? What can i do to draw "faster". Hope you can help me.

Comment: I am wondering if 9600 (Bauds?) is enough to channel 20KHz without loss or lag... Maybe you want to sample the data to plot?

Comment: But the 9600 BaudsRate is related to the frequency that i am using to get the samples ?